# imputation only for feature selection step but not for model input in sklearn pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to do a feature selection (removing correlated features) before the LGBMClassifier step. However, many feature selection methods require no missing value in X. How to do imputation only for feature selection step but not for model input in the sklearn pipeline? Here is my current code:

```
full_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('imp_selector', SelectFromModel(
            LinearSVC(C=0.01, penalty="l1", dual=False))),
        ('model', LGBMClassifier())
    ])
```

Do I need to create a new transformer?